# Where to change listen port inside php-fpm.conf at ubuntu?

Tags: php

I want to change the port which php-fpm are listen.

When I use osx, I can simply go **php-fpm.conf**, and change:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

to

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9999
```

Now I'm use ubuntu, where can I change the port?

Comment: Did you try looking at `/etc/php/[VERSION]/fpm/`?

Comment: @MichaelHirschler
Yes, I can find php-fpm.conf. But I can't find "listen = 127.0.0.1:9000" inside php-fpm.conf. So I don't know where to write "listen = 127.0.0.1:9999"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the file you looking for is /etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.

Answer (score 0):

In MacOs Ventura /etc/php/8.2/php-fpm.d/www.conf